# Rename the [sequential] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [sequential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequential) tag has the following usage guidance:

> Implementation questions about sequential neural networks

However, it's attracting lots of questions that have nothing to do with that.

Can we rename this tag?

This tag should be named [sequential-neural-networks] if that's what it's "supposed" to mean. The *actual* usage is all over the map because the current name is ambiguous and most people don't read usage guidance; for example, the most recent usage is sequential search.

Comment: What do you want to rename it to? `[sequential - Stand with Ukraine]` may fit with the zeitgeist.

Comment: @CodyGray I wouldn't object to that.

Comment: Right. Well, I was perhaps a bit too flippant in attempting humor, which interfered with my primary point, which is that you've failed to suggest something concrete to actually rename this tag to. I would go even further and tug at the fundamental assumption that a tag's meaning is determined by the tag wiki as opposed to being determined by its actual usage (denotation vs. connotation, I suppose, the age-old debate of lexicographers). It does not appear that the tag's actual usage relates in any way to neural networks, so is it even appropriate to rename the tag to enforce such a limitation?

Comment: @CodyGray Right now it doesn't reflect much of anything, so maybe it would be better to have a larger retag effort (or outright burnination). The tag usage guidance does identify a specific programming topic that it's *supposed* to be used for, but the name itself is quite ambiguous and the fact that most people don't read the usage guidance means that its actual usage is all over the map.

Comment: 821 questions, 26 of which show up in a search for `[sequential] neural network`. Seems like less effort to create a `sequential-neural-network` tag for the few questions it applies to, and then burn this one.

Comment: May as well include [`[nonsequential]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nonsequential) into the discussion.  There are a few other `sequential-*` (-workflow, -number) that may fit some of the questions but they look to be used much less often.

Comment: @kaya3 That should probably be an answer....